# Check to make sure the host is up or that the database listener is running on that host

Tags: oracle, listener, oracle12c

i have a problem when i try to install Oracle Interprise Manager Cloud Control 12c

[image]

I checked it is open [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kipW.png)

[image]

What should i do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the network listener with "lsnrctl status" from the command line and make sure it is running (it will have its own service on Windows), and that the database has registered 
   a service name with it.
2. If the listener is up and running correctly, make sure there is no system firewall blocking access to port 1521.
3. Try using the IP address of the host instead of the hostname, or switch to "localhost" if everything is running on the same system.